# Ruby on Rails: :include on a polymorphic association with submodels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, polymorphic-associations, eager-loading, rails-activerecord

When working with a polymorphic association, is it possible to run an include on submodels that are only present in some types?

Example:

```
class Container
  belongs_to :contents, :polymorphic => true
end
class Food
  has_one :container
  belongs_to :expiration
end
class Things
  has_one :container
end
```

In the view I'm going to want to do something like:

```
<% c = Containers.all %>
<% if c.class == Food %>
  <%= food.expiration %>
<% end %>
```

Therefore, I'd like to eager load the expirations when I load up c, because I know I will need every last one of them.  Is there any way to do so?  Just defining a regular :include gets me errors because not all enclosed types have a submodel expiration.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Edited Answer**

I recently found out that Rails supports eager loading of polymorphic associations when you filter by the polymorphic type column. So there is no need to declare fake associations.

```
class Container
  belongs_to :content, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Now query the `Container` by `container_type`.

```
containers_with_food = Container.find_all_by_content_type("Food", 
                           :include => :content)

containers_with_thing = Container.find_all_by_content_type("Thing", 
                           :include => :content)
```

**Old Answer**

This is a hack as there is no direct way to include the polymorphic objects in one query.

```
class Container
  belongs_to :contents, :polymorphic => true
  # add dummy associations for all the contents.
  # this association should not be used directly
  belongs_to :food
  belongs_to :thing
end
```

Now query the `Container` by `container_type`.

```
containers_with_food = Container.find_all_by_content_type("Food", 
                           :include => :food)

containers_with_thing = Container.find_all_by_content_type("Thing", 
                           :include => :thing)
```

That results in two SQL calls to the database ( actually it is 4 calls as rails executes one SQL for every `:include`)

There is no way to do this in one SQL as you need different column set for different content types.

**Caveat:** The dummy associations on `Content` class should not be used directly as it will result in unexpected results.

E.g: Lets say the first object in the `contents` table contains food.

```
Content.first.food # will work
Content.first.thing
```

The second call will not work. It might give you a `Thing` object with the same id as the `Food` object pointed by `Content`.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on some new information, take a look.

Comment: In what version of ActiveRecord does eager-loading of polymorphic associations work? It's not working for me in 3.2.3

Comment: @nicholaides It should work in 3.2.3. The eager loading happens only when you filter by the polymorphic type column. What is the error you encountered?

Comment: "The eager loading happens only when you filter by the polymorphic type column". Ah, I didn't catch that part. I took the liberti of updating your answer. I hope you don't mind!