# Eager loading for polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

Not sure this could fall in performance section as well as model/database section, so here goes....

Let's say I have 3 models:

```
Movie {
has_one :interest, :as => :resource
}
Song {
has_one :interest, :as => :resource
}
Story {
has_one :interest, :as => :resource
}
```

and ...

```
Interest {
belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
}
```

Now, if I need a list of all interests for all movies, and I want to show also the date those Movies objects were created (to say how old they were), then I use the lookup on resource_type attribute and then @some_interest.resource.created_at.

The problem with this is if I have 100 movie interests, then I will get 101 queries right ? So linear degradation. I tried using :include => [:resource] in my query call, but it says cannot use include in polymorphic associations.

How can I either eager load or optimize this problem to avoid this severe degradation ??

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: I think this will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390017/ruby-on-rails-include-on-a-polymorphic-association-with-submodels

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [searchlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic), there is a special syntax to deal with polymorphic relationships that may help. You can search on the `has` side of the relationship by specifying the name of the related class suffixed with `type`.

E.g. given your models, you ought to be able to do something like this to get movies created in the last 90 days:

`Interest.resource_movie_type_created_at_gt(Time.now-90.days)`

Searchlogic sets up the join on the related model for you, which should allay performance concerns.

Of course you can always write your own SQL using the `find_by_sql` method.

PS. one very helpful trick is to [turn on logging in the Rails console](http://www.fromjavatoruby.com/2008/10/irbconsole-tweaks.html) while writing searches. This allows you to see the SQL generated right in the console without having to dig through the logs.