# N+1 query with rails polymorphic association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, performance

I have two models.

Album

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :post, as: :post_module, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Post (which has *title* attribute)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post_module, polymorphic: true
end
```

and here is my template

```
<% @albums.each do |album| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= link_to album.post.title, edit_admin_album_path(album) %>&nbsp;<br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I tried to use `:includes` and `:references` to avoid N + 1 query.

```
def index
    @albums = Album.includes(:post).references(:post).to_a
end
```

But it seems like the N + 1 query still occurs. What's wrong with this?

```
SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT `albums`.`id` AS t0_r0, `albums`.`product_num` AS t0_r1, `albums`.`created_at` AS t0_r2, `albums`.`updated_at` AS t0_r3, `posts`.`id` AS t1_r0, `posts`.`title` AS t1_r1, `posts`.`date` AS t1_r2, `posts`.`post_module_id` AS t1_r3, `posts`.`post_module_type` AS t1_r4, `posts`.`created_at` AS t1_r5, `posts`.`updated_at` AS t1_r6 FROM `albums` LEFT OUTER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`post_module_id` = `albums`.`id` AND `posts`.`post_module_type` = 'Album'
Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`post_module_id` = 18 AND `posts`.`post_module_type` = 'Album' ORDER BY `posts`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`post_module_id` = 20 AND `posts`.`post_module_type` = 'Album' ORDER BY `posts`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`post_module_id` = 21 AND `posts`.`post_module_type` = 'Album' ORDER BY `posts`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`post_module_id` = 22 AND `posts`.`post_module_type` = 'Album' ORDER BY `posts`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`post_module_id` = 23 AND `posts`.`post_module_type` = 'Album' ORDER BY `posts`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It seems N + 1 occurs even when I don't call `album.post.title' in each loop with @album =Album.all

Comment: try Album.includes(:post) only

Comment: It gets me same result :(

Comment: Try Album.all(:include => :post)

Comment: can u post, what u have changed in your def index ?

Comment: I just put '@albums = Album.all(:include => :post)' in def index as you said.

Comment: plz try Album.all(:include => :post_module) . This may work. because in your album model, you have saved relation with post as post_module not as post. Thats why its not getting.

Comment: error throws-Association named 'post_module' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?- I think Album is Post model's post_module association...

Comment: There is post_module model. Can you post this model?

Comment: there is no actual post_module model. check this. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Please try Album.all.includes(:post => :polymorphic)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying eager loading in a polymorphic association.

Please refer the following site for more details

[Polymorphic Association and Eager Loading Issues](http://ashokk-blog.blogspot.in/2012/06/polymorphic-association-and-eager.html)

please try

```
Album.all.includes(:post => :post_module)
```

Comment: it throws error 'Association named 'polymorphic' was not found' T T

Answer (score 0):

See if this answer applies for you

[Ruby on Rails: :include on a polymorphic association with submodels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390017/ruby-on-rails-include-on-a-polymorphic-association-with-submodels)

Comment: Ok, try this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390017/ruby-on-rails-include-on-a-polymorphic-association-with-submodels

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. Did the answer I linked answer to your situation?